# <?php Longhand form not being recognized at all

Tags: php, configuration

I recently reformatted my computer, and now I can't get back into existing projects due to some weird error with the long tags not being picked up (by the compiler?).

Note: I added short_open_tag:On to php.ini

After this, the compiler(?) picked up all the short hand tags and processed the code fine. The problem is, wherever the longhand implementation `<?php #code ?>` is used, I get an error. There doesn't seem to be a long_open_tag either, since it's meant to work by default.

How do I get my compiler/web app to recognize longhand?

**EDIT/Solution: **

I added `short_open_tag:On` right at the top of php.ini, after reading through most of the file, I saw `short_open_tag:Off` down later, clearly overwriting the previous line. Now the rest of the longhand code worked fine.

Comment: Baby step through your apache/IIS Configuration/handlers for the PHP executional, as these "long hand" `<?php ?>` should be parsed by default. Only thing which needs extra tweaks would be the short tags `<? ?>`

Comment: `I get an error` and what is the error?

Comment: Replaced Larvel with Configuration. This question is in now way related to Larvel